# How do I write data binary to gcs with ruby efficiently?

Tags: ruby, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to upload data binary directly to GCP storage, without writing the file to disk. Below is the code snippet I have created to get to the state that I am going to be at.

```rb
require 'google/cloud/storage'

bucket_name = '-----'

data = File.open('image_block.jpg', 'rb') {|file| file.read }


storage = Google::Cloud::Storage.new("project_id": "maybe-i-will-tell-u")
bucket  = storage.bucket bucket_name, skip_lookup: true
```

Now I want to directly put this `data` into a file on gcs, without having to write a file to disk.

Is there an efficient way we can do that?

I tried the following code

```
to_send = StringIO.new(data).read

bucket.create_file to_send, "image_inder_11111.jpg"
```

but this throws an error saying

```
/google/cloud/storage/bucket.rb:2898:in `file?': path name contains null byte (ArgumentError)
    from /home/inder/.gem/gems/google-cloud-storage-1.36.1/lib/google/cloud/storage/bucket.rb:2898:in `ensure_io_or_file_exists!'
    from /home/inder/.gem/gems/google-cloud-storage-1.36.1/lib/google/cloud/storage/bucket.rb:1566:in `create_file'
    from champa.rb:14:in `<main>'
```

Comment: According to the docs for [Creating a File](https://googleapis.dev/ruby/google-cloud-storage/latest/index.html#creating-a-file) you can pass in-memory data as a `StringIO`.

Comment: @Stefan will you mind to share a small snippet, I tried as above but couldn't get success

Comment: It should be `to_send = StringIO.new(data)`, i.e. without `.read` (which would return a string again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @stefan, It should be to_send = StringIO.new(data), i.e. without .read (which would return a string again)